# Can not write proper filtering queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

There is such content type model:

```
class CTModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    sport = models.ForeignKey(SportTypes)
```

QuerySets:

```
user_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(UserProfile)
current_sport = Sports.objects.get(name='Football')
rest_sports = Sports.objects.filter(name__in=RANDOM LIST OF GAMES).exclude(name='Football')

# Here I want to get all users who play 'Football'
users_play_football = CTModel.objects.filter(content_type=user_type, sport=current_sport)

# Here I want to get all users, who play Football,
# but at the same time, does not play any other games from 'rest_sports'
users = users_play_football.exclude(sport=rest_sports)
```

I want to get `users` with some content (users) just in case if users play **just** Football, and if users play any other games, `users` should not include such users. Now, if users play both 'Football' and somethings from `rest_sports`, these users are not excluded from `users`.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with the logic of my QuerySets. In the approach above queryset excluded just `rest_sports` of a user, and does not remove user itself from `users`.

Here there is a solution:

```
users_play_football = CTModel.objects.filter(content_type=user_type, sport=current_sport).values_list('object_id', flat=True)
users_w_rest_games = CTModel.objects.filter(content_type=user_type, sport=rest_sports).values_list('object_id', flat=True)

if users_w_rest_games:
    users = users_play_football.exclude(object_id__in=users_w_rest_games)
else:
    users = users_play_football
```

In my case it seems that `.exclude` does not work as needed with raw QuerySets, because `exclude` actually does not exclude anything. So thats the reason why I use `values_list('object_id', flat=True)` in order to provide users' `object_id`'s explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
users = users_play_football.exclude(sport__in=rest_sports)
```